# How to select an element inside an iframe and then run an "each" method on those elements

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

So I'm trying to build a wall of videos that automatically loops and is formatted using iframes. I can't use the html5 video tag property "loop" because Chrome isn't responding to it, so I'm using a jquery loop. I know my loop works when I don't include iframes, but I'm struggling to implement it within iframes heres what I have right now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe width="473" height="353"
<video autoplay src="LC10.mp4">
</video>
</iframe>

<iframe width="473" height="353"
<video autoplay src="LC11.mp4">
</video>
</iframe>

<iframe width="473" height="353"
<video autoplay src="LC12.mp4">
</video></iframe>

<script>
$("iframe").each (function(){
.contents().find("video")
}); 

$("video").each(function(){

 $(this).on("ended",function(e){
 var vid = $(this).get(0);
 vid.currentTime = 0;
 vid.play();
 });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using iframes for this, if the video source is hosted by you then why not set one video tag and loop through the videos, add some eventlisteners to that element, using javascript. Once the video has finished move on to the next one. You can store the videos inside an array and loop through the array as the video ends. You could even add a Next/Previous button to change the array.